# How to show how much stock is left for each variation in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've setup several variations in WooCommerce and I want to show how much stock is left out of the total stock.

ex:

```
[Attribute Name] 3/5
[Attribute Name] 1/5
[Attribute Name] SOLD OUT!
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use woocommerce plugin for showing the remaining stock. Here is the link :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-availability-chart/

Please read carefully whole the documentation and support before using it. I didn't use it.